# Difficulty with a Visual Basic calculation

Tags: vb.net

just have a problem with visual basic.  I was trying to make a simple conversion program, but the program keeps giving me the wrong answer. I've also coded this out in Java, where it gave me the answer I was expecting.  I don't know what's going on here. Here is a sample of the code.  The numbers I have been entering are 10 for alienYears to convert, 440 for alienYearLength and 25.5 for alienDayLength. It should come out to about 12. something but I keep getting 218.something.
Thank you

```
Dim alienYears As Decimal = CDec(txtYearsToConvert.Text)
        Dim alienYearLength As Decimal = CDec(txtDaysOnAlienPlanet.Text)
        Dim alienDayLength As Decimal = CDec(txtDaysOnAlienPlanet.Text)
        Dim alienHoursYears As Decimal = ((alienYears * alienYearLength) * alienDayLength)
        Dim earthHourYears As Decimal = (8851.25)
        Dim earthConversion As Decimal = (alienHoursYears / earthHourYears)
        txtAgeOnEarth.Text = CStr(earthConversion)
```

Comment: (a) In VBA you can not assign a value to a variable as part of the declaration statement, so this is probably VB.Net (please update your tag if it is, or let us know if it really is VBA so that we can show you how to avoid the compile error).  (b) `Dim alienYearLength As Decimal = CDec(txtDaysOnAlienPlanet.Text)` and `Dim alienDayLength As Decimal = CDec(txtDaysOnAlienPlanet.Text)` are going to set `alienYearLength` and `alienDayLength` to the same value.

Comment: @YowE3K actually he can do that with a variant `Dim alienYears As Variant: alienYears = CDec("25.5")` but not directly while declaring as you stated.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes I noticed his usage after posting my comment

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo here (vvvv), do you mean txtYears(something)? There's no way this could be meaningful using the input from the same textbox.

```
    Dim alienYears As Decimal = CDec(txtYearsToConvert.Text)
'                                            VVVV
    Dim alienYearLength As Decimal = CDec(txtDaysOnAlienPlanet.Text)
    Dim alienDayLength As Decimal = CDec(txtDaysOnAlienPlanet.Text)
    Dim alienHoursYears As Decimal = ((alienYears * alienYearLength) * alienDayLength)
    Dim earthHourYears As Decimal = (8851.25)
    Dim earthConversion As Decimal = (alienHoursYears / earthHourYears)
    txtAgeOnEarth.Text = CStr(earthConversion)
```

Comment: I think the typo is on the next line for alienDayLength surely it should use something like CDec(txtHoursOnAlienPlanet.Text)